Conditional Filtering Within a Function in R
Using R, I'm trying to include conditional filtering into a function that I'm writing. I want the conditional filter to select rows with specific account numbers. Below is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do.
df<-data.frame(ActID=c("AAAAA","TTTTTT","FFFFFF","EEEEEE","GGGGG"),ActNum=c(1234,900,901,2345,3456))  

dfun<-function(df,p,k){
  df<-df%>%filter(ifelse(p=="Y",ActNum %in% k,!(ActNum %in% c(0))))
}

dataset1<-dfun(df,p="Y",k=c(1234,2345,3456))




When I use the ifelse function, within the filter function, nothing seems to actually happen. I tried changing the k=c(1234,2345,3456) to a list but that didn't work either. I also tried to use the case_when function from the dplyr package but I get the same results as the ifelse function. I'm hoping to get some ideas on how to get the conditional filter to actually work. Thank you.

The one point is that your function needs to return something and the other point is that you need if here and not ifelse, use dfun <- function(df, p, k) { df |> filter(if (p == "Y") { df$ActNum %in% k} else {!(ActNum %in% c(0))})}

p=="Y" has a length of 1. So that entire ifelse will just return TRUE, not a logical vector of length n.

Here is what I think you are looking for:
dfun <- \(df,p,k){
  if(p == "y"){
    df |> 
      dplyr::filter(ActNum %in% k)
  } else {
    print("No matching account numbers!")
  }
  
}

k=c(1234,2345,3456)

dfun(df,p = "y",k = k)

   

       ActID ActNum
    1  AAAAA   1234
    2 EEEEEE   2345
    3  GGGGG   3456


   

Hope it helps!
